# The anchorPoint is ignored when creating Marker on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

The Google Maps API v3 documentation says that the MarkerOptions can include anchorPoint to specify the offset (move the icon relative to the marker):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

**I have tried to use anchorPoint, but it seems to be ignored. What foolish mistake have I made?**

Here's some code which creates two markers; one with an anchorPoint and the other with the default (marker is anchored to bottom centre of the image). I'd expect one to move down a bit, but they stay horizontally aligned.

```
var oMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('div_map'), { zoom: 25, center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.14,-1.4), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN });

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.14, -1.403), map: oMap, title: 'Normal', icon: 'http://www.merlinrocket.co.uk/images/mroa_logo.gif' });
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.14, -1.407), anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(50, 50), map: oMap, title: 'Offset', icon: 'http://www.merlinrocket.co.uk/images/mroa_logo.gif' });
```

I have found lots of code examples where {url/size/origin/anchor} are passed to the `icon:` part of the MarkerOptions, but I do not wish to use that method. Regardless, the code I'm using above seems to adhere to the documentation, yet doesn't make any visible difference.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: *anchorPoint: The offset from the marker's position to the tip of an InfoWindow that has been opened with the marker as anchor.* So, it is not ignored, there is no any infowindow.

Comment: AAAAARRRRGGGGG!!!! And there was me claiming I had read the documentation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My foolish mistake was that I hadn't read the documentation carefully. The anchorPoint is the offset of any infoWindow that opens from that marker, not the icon offset.

Thanks to @AntoJurković

Comment: Not very useful answer. Great you fixed it but what is the correct property to set?

Comment: marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: latLon,
   icon: {
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(offset,offset),
    url: url
   },
   map: map
  });